# Is $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}$=$\sup\{f(x):a\leq x\leq b\}-\inf\{f(x):a\leq x\leq b\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Is $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}$=$\sup\{f(x):a\leq x\leq b\}-\inf\{f(x):a\leq x\leq b\}=M-m$ (M being the sup and m the inf)

Possible proof:

For all $|f(x')-f(x'')|$ we know that $m\leq f(x'),f(x'')\leq M$. Hence,
$-(M-m) \leq f(x')-f(x'')\leq M-m$ which implies $|f(x')-f(x'')|\leq M-m$.
Therefore, $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}\leq M-m$.

Now I'm stuck as to how to show the other inequality. Is the statement even true (counter-examples?) or can anyone show me how to proceed with the proof.

Edit:

Suppose $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}< M-m$. Hence, $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}+m < M$

Therefore, there exists $f(x'), a\leq x'\leq b$ s.t $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}+m< f(x')$. Also, $m< f(x')-\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}$

Similarly, there exists $f(x''), a\leq x''\leq b$ s.t $f(x'') < f(x')-\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}$

This implies that $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}<f(x')-f(x'')$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, $\sup\{|f(x')-f(x'')|:a\leq x',x''\leq b\}=M-m$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The second statement after the Edit, I fail to see why.

Comment: @user284331 Because M and m are sup and inf repectively. I have edited it.

Comment: Okay, I see that now, you may look at my answer for a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $a\leq x\leq b$ and $a\leq y\leq b$, we have $f(x)-f(y)\leq M-f(y)\leq M-m$, and we also have $f(y)-f(x)\leq M-m$ with the same reason, so $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M-m$, this gives $\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: a\leq x,y\leq b\}\leq M-m$.

On the other hand, still, $a\leq x,y\leq b$, we have $f(x)-f(y)\leq|f(x)-f(y)|$ and hence $f(x)\leq f(y)+\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: a\leq x,y\leq b\}$, this is true for all $a\leq x\leq b$, we have $M\leq f(y)+\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: a\leq x,y\leq b\}$, so $M-\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|:a\leq x,y\leq b\}\leq f(y)$, this is true for all $a\leq x\leq b$, so $M-\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: a\leq x,y\leq b\}\leq m$, and hence $M-m\leq\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: a\leq x,y,\leq b\}$.